# Salesforce Sans font in <apex:slds> not rendering in iOS safari

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, slds

I am using `<apex:slds>` in a VF page where I have been able to use the Salesforce Sans Light and Regular fonts in CSS styling and it works fine on computer browsers such as edge and chrome:

[image]

but when viewing on a  mobile device the fonts come out with no styling or fonts:

[image]

Does `<apex:slds>` have limited support for iOS safari browsers? Or is there something I need to unblock?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Since [Classic is not supported in mobile browsers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browser_aloha.htm&type=5), I assume that Visualforce is not supported either.